# Run SFTP client as "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" in a scheduled task

Tags: windows, sftp

I have set up a script to get some data into files and then upload them to a SFTP server.

I have the command

> `SFTP -i \path\to\.ssh\id_rsa -b \path\to\ftpcommands user@someserver.com`

the `sftp` commands batch file just has `mput *.csv`

When I run this from a command prompt it works fine.
When I set this up as a scheduled task running under the system profile it skips over the `sftp` line. no errors. I see output from all the other commands in the script as I have redirected output to a log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely the `sftp` is "skipped over".

It is more likely that you do not redirect an "error output" to the log file

Use `> log 2>&1` to redirect both standard and error output. I believe that will reveal the root cause of your problems.